# Dock indication about different application instances

Tags: macos, dock

I miss a feature of the windows taskbar; I could see each application instance separately keeping an eye on my actual open Windows and not Apps.. This is useful especially in debugging, keeping two Chrome windows open - comparing - etc etc..

Is it possible to alter the Dock in a way that will give me indication of the Instances of One app, rather than a single application icon which I have to right click in order to see how many - if at all - instances are open?

I am asking either for Add-on apps, improvements, hidden gems, settings, anything...

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: MBP 2014 - i5,16GB

Comment: The dock does show an icon per instance of an app - opening a window does not create a new instance. Opening an app again - note you have to do this via command line does add another icon

Comment: Ok Mark, I guess new instance isn't the correct choice of words, but you get the picture;-)

Answer (score 1):

There's a Multi-Touch gesture that can show you all the instances of one app. Swiping downwards with either three or four fingers (configurable in System Preferences > Trackpad > More Gestures) opens "App Exposé", a handy birds-eye view of all your open windows in the frontmost app. It's not the same as an indicator in the always-present Dock, I know, but I think this can be one of the best options you'll get without 3rd-party software (assuming such software exists).

Comment: Hm , I knew this one , but it requires an action... Not want I want